# RVM unbound variable

Tags: ruby, rvm

I am trying to use RVM to install Ruby 1.9.2 but I get the following error when I run this commmand `rvm install 1.9.2`:

```
**-bash**: rvm_env_string: unbound variable

Could not detect ruby version/name for installation, please be more specific.
```

Pretty sure RVM runs on exactly that argument, any idea why the rvm_env_string is not bound?

Comment: what shell/version/system is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like you have:

```
set -o nounset
```

find it and turn it off.

RVM1 is not compatible with it, I Will work on RVM2 to work everywhere and always the same.

Comment: This version says that rvm scripts now work with nounset. I still see this error. Any idea? https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/tag/1.29.3

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have the latest rvm?  Try:

1. `rvm get latest`
2. or as a last resort `rvm implode` and then reinstall rvm

Comment: No luck, I reinstalled just in case but the error remains. Additionally, when I attempt to source the file ( ~ $ source .rvm/scripts/rvm/ ) I get this error ->
-bash: .rvm/scripts/rvm/: Not a directory

Comment: @skeetinhalligan remove the / -> `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm`

Comment: @mpapis just does this instead, although maybe it's more informative: 

~ $ source .rvm/scripts/rvm  => 
-bash: rvm_user_install_flag: unbound variable

Comment: what shell/version/system is it?

Comment: @mpapis bash v 3.2, rvm v 1.15.5, osx lion